# Create a tarball of absolute file path

Tags: tar

I need to create a tgz of files with their absolute file names.
The problem is: the receiver of the tgz expects (which is a embedded product based on linux) a root hierarchy like this (displayable with `tar tf`) :

> /usr/foo/bar/
>   /usr/foo/bar/blabla1
>   /usr/foo/bar/blabla2
>   /usr/foo/bar/blabla3

On my side, I only have a home and "/home/guillaume/project/totar/usr/foo/" and I can't touch my root directory.

What can I do to "simulate" the root hierarchy of the target inside my tarball and obtain the same file list as above?
I thought about chroot but is there a lesser overkill solution?

Comment: Please read http://superuser.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The --transform option of tar is perfect for me.

```
 --transform=EXPRESSIONR, --xform=EXPRESSION
              Use sed replace EXPRESSION to transform file names.
```